# SQL query to produce a time x day grid from a list of timestamps?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Structures of my tables are as follow.

Table Name : timetable

[timetable http://www.4shared.com/download/MYafV7-6ce/timetableTable.png](http://www.4shared.com/download/MYafV7-6ce/timetableTable.png)

Table Name : slot_table

[timetable http://www.4shared.com/download/9Lp_CBn2ba/slot_table.png](http://www.4shared.com/download/9Lp_CBn2ba/slot_table.png)

Table Name : instructor(this table is not required for this particular problem)

I want to show the resultant data in my android app in a timetable format somewhat like this:

[random http://www.4shared.com/download/oAGiUXVAba/random.png](http://www.4shared.com/download/oAGiUXVAba/random.png)

**Question** : What query i should write so that subjects of particular days with respective slots will be the result of the query?

1)The days should be in order like monday,tuesday,wednesday.

2)If monday has 2 subjects in 2 different slots then it should display like this :

```
Day         7:30-9:10AM           9:20-11:00AM        

Monday      Android Workshop      Operating System
```

This is just a sample.

P.S:As timetable format is required,all the subjects with slot ids of all the days(monday to saturday) must be there in it.

**Edit** :

I tried this

```
select day,subject,slot from timetable,slot_table where timetable.slotid = slot_table.slotid
```

which gave a result :

[a http://www.4shared.com/download/uMU7NA8Oce/random1.png](http://www.4shared.com/download/uMU7NA8Oce/random1.png)

But i want it in a timetable format which i am not having an idea how to do that.

**Edit :**

Timetable sample format is something like this :

[image: a]

**Edit** :

I wrote a query

```
select timetable.day,count(slot_table.subject) as no_of_classes from timetable,slot_table where timetable.slotid = slot_table.slotid group by timetable.day
```

which resulted in

[a http://www.4shared.com/download/rZW20_g8ce/random2.png](http://www.4shared.com/download/rZW20_g8ce/random2.png)

So now it shows monday has 2 classes in 2 slots,Tuesday has 1 class in 1 slot and so on.

Now any help on a query which can show the two slots(timings) on monday?

**Solution** :

```
select timetable.day,max(case when (slot='7:30-9:10AM') then slot_table.subject END) as "7:30-9:10AM",max(case when (slot='9:20-11:00AM') then slot_table.subject END) as "9:20-11:00AM",max(case when (slot='11:10-12:50PM') then slot_table.subject END) as "11:10-12:50PM",max(case when (slot='1:40-3:20PM') then slot_table.subject END) as "1:40-3:20PM",    max(case when (slot='3:30-5:00PM') then slot_table.subject END) as "3:30-5:00PM" from timetable join slot_table on timetable.slotid = slot_table.slotid group by timetable.day
```

Result :

[a http://www.4shared.com/download/1w7Tyicfce/random3.png](http://www.4shared.com/download/1w7Tyicfce/random3.png)

Comment: `MAX(CASE WHEN slot_text='...' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` for each hour interval

Comment: @MihaiPlease check my edited answer.Your suggestion helped.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called a PIVOT query. In one of these, you have a select which gives the data in rows, like your result just under the EDIT (Day, subject, slot). Then you need to specify the values of the row you want to 'pivot' to become columns (slot in this example). Because a Pivot relies on the values of the column to be pivoted it can be difficult to write a general query, and the Postgres Wiki has an example using dymanic SQL and lots of code generating it at http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pivot_query

In your case, given that slots look like they're fixed and you might be able to hard-code them (that's a decision you'll have make yourself).

NB I am not a Postgres user, but it looks like it can do it (and I would have been very surprised if it couldn't).

Comment: Please check my edited answer.Your suggestion helped.Thanks for letting me know about the pivot query which is very important.

Comment: That looks about it, doesn't it? Cheers -

Comment: Thanks.[Check it please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328396/retrieving-sqlite-table-data-in-android-app) Could you please have a look here?I am stuck with another silly problem.

Comment: Posted! Take out the else!

Answer (score 1):

This is a [pivot](/questions/tagged/pivot) or [crosstab](/questions/tagged/crosstab) query. PostgreSQL has only limited support for these via [the `crosstab` function in the `tablefunc` module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html).

It can sometimes be better to just deal with this in the application, accumulating the data into a table as you read each data point.

Comment: Please check my edited answer.Your suggestion helped.Thanks.However i didn't use the crosstab function in the tablefunc module for this specific problem.