# Retrieving sqlite table data in Android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am retrieving my sqlite table data successfully in my Android app. However it has some minor problem which I am not able to figure out.

**Code Snippet:**

```
int flag=1;
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {



                    String day = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("day"));

                    String slot1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("7:30-9:10AM"));    
                    String slot2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("9:20-11:00AM"));
                    String slot3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("11:10-12:50PM"));
                    String slot4 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("1:40-3:20PM"));
                    String slot5 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("3:30-5:00PM"));


                            TableRow tr=new TableRow(viewtimetable.this);

                            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                       LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                            if(flag==1)
                            {

                                TextView col1=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                                 col1.setText("Day");
                                 col1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                 col1.setTextSize(15);
                                 tr.addView(col1);


                                TextView col2=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                                 col2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                 col2.setTextSize(15);
                                 col2.setText("7:30-9:10AM");
                                 col2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                 tr.addView(col2);

                                TextView col3=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                                 col3.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                 col3.setText("9:20-11:00AM");
                                 col3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                 col3.setTextSize(15);
                                 tr.addView(col3);

                                TextView col4=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                                 col4.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                 col4.setText("11:10-12:50PM");
                                 col4.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                 col4.setTextSize(15);
                                 tr.addView(col4);

                                TextView col5=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                                 col5.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                 col5.setText("1:40-3:20PM");
                                 col5.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                 col5.setTextSize(15);
                                 tr.addView(col5);

                                TextView col6=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                                 col6.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                 col6.setText("3:30-5:00PM");
                                 col6.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                 col6.setTextSize(15);
                                 tr.addView(col6);

                                 tv.addView(tr);

                                 final View vline = new View(viewtimetable.this);

                                 vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
                                 vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);



                            tv.addView(vline);

                            flag=0;   

                            }

                            else
                            {



                        TextView b=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                            //String stime=json_data.getString("day");
                            b.setText(day);
                            b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            b.setTextSize(15);
                            tr.addView(b);


                           TextView b1=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                           TextView b2=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                           TextView b3=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                           TextView b4=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                           TextView b5=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);


                            b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                            b1.setTextSize(15);
                            b1.setTextColor(Color.RED);


                            b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                            b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            b2.setTextSize(15);


                            b3.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                            b3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            b3.setTextSize(15);
                            //tr.addView(b3);  

                            b4.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                            b4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            b4.setTextSize(15);
                            //tr.addView(b4);     

                            b5.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                            b5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            b5.setTextSize(15);
                            //tr.addView(b5); 



                            if(day.equals("Monday"))
                            {

                                if(slot1 != null){ 
                                b1.setText(slot1);
                                }
                                if(slot2 != null)
                                {
                                    b2.setText(slot2);  
                                }
                                if(slot3 != null)
                                {
                                    b3.setText(slot3);  
                                }
                                if(slot4 != null)
                                {
                                    b4.setText(slot4);  
                                }
                                if(slot5 != null)
                                {
                                    b5.setText(slot5);  
                                }

                             }



                            else if(day.equals("Tuesday"))
                            {

                                if(slot1 != null){ 
                                b1.setText(slot1);
                                }
                                if(slot2 != null)
                                {
                                    b2.setText(slot2);  
                                }
                                if(slot3 != null)
                                {
                                    b3.setText(slot3);  
                                }
                                if(slot4 != null)
                                {
                                    b4.setText(slot4);  
                                }
                                if(slot5 != null)
                                {
                                    b5.setText(slot5);  
                                }

                             }


                            else if(day.equals("Wednesday"))
                            {
                                if(slot1 != null){ 
                                b1.setText(slot1);
                                }
                                if(slot2 != null)
                                {
                                    b2.setText(slot2);  
                                }
                                if(slot3 != null)
                                {
                                    b3.setText(slot3);  
                                }
                                if(slot4 != null)
                                {
                                    b4.setText(slot4);  
                                }
                                if(slot5 != null)
                                {
                                    b5.setText(slot5);  
                                }

                             }


                            else if(day.equals("Thursday"))
                                {
                                    if(slot1 != null){ 
                                    b1.setText(slot1);
                                    }
                                    if(slot2 != null)
                                    {
                                        b2.setText(slot2);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot3 != null)
                                    {
                                        b3.setText(slot3);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot4 != null)
                                    {
                                        b4.setText(slot4);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot5 != null)
                                    {
                                        b5.setText(slot5);  
                                    }

                                 }

                             else if(day.equals("Friday"))
                            {

                                if(slot1 != null){ 
                                b1.setText(slot1);
                                }
                                if(slot2 != null)
                                {
                                    b2.setText(slot2);  
                                }
                                if(slot3 != null)
                                {
                                    b3.setText(slot3);  
                                }
                                if(slot4 != null)
                                {
                                    b4.setText(slot4);  
                                }
                                if(slot5 != null)
                                {
                                    b5.setText(slot5);  
                                }

                             }         

                            else if(day.equals("Saturday"))
                                    {

                                        if(slot1 != null){ 
                                        b1.setText(slot1);
                                        }
                                        if(slot2 != null)
                                        {
                                            b2.setText(slot2);  
                                        }
                                        if(slot3 != null)
                                        {
                                            b3.setText(slot3);  
                                        }
                                        if(slot4 != null)
                                        {
                                            b4.setText(slot4);  
                                        }
                                        if(slot5 != null)
                                        {
                                            b5.setText(slot5);  
                                        }

                                     }

                              tr.addView(b1);  
                              tr.addView(b2);
                              tr.addView(b3);
                              tr.addView(b4);
                              tr.addView(b5);
                              tv.addView(tr);
```

**Result :**

[a http://www.4shared.com/download/mhKMKta4ba/random4.png](http://www.4shared.com/download/mhKMKta4ba/random4.png)

**Question :**

I wonder why Friday's row is not getting displayed?

P.S: As I have successfully retrieved all the required data except Friday's data hence there is some minor issue with the above code snippet only I guess.

**Edit :**

The problem is in else block. As the first data is Friday and the else block don't get executed for the first iteration hence the problem arises.

Tried removing else block and it generates exception:

> specified child already has parent.you must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

**Solution :**

What I did is inside the loop I created a new `Tablerow` and then added `views` to that row.

**Final Correct Code :**

```
 TableLayout tv=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
            tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            int flag=1;
            TableRow tr=new TableRow(viewtimetable.this);

            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                       LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView col1=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
            col1.setText("Day");
            col1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            col1.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(col1);


           TextView col2=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
            col2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            col2.setTextSize(15);
            col2.setText("7:30-9:10AM");
            col2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            tr.addView(col2);

           TextView col3=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
            col3.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            col3.setText("9:20-11:00AM");
            col3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            col3.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(col3);

           TextView col4=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
            col4.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            col4.setText("11:10-12:50PM");
            col4.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            col4.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(col4);

           TextView col5=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
            col5.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            col5.setText("1:40-3:20PM");
            col5.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            col5.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(col5);

           TextView col6=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
            col6.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            col6.setText("3:30-5:00PM");
            col6.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            col6.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(col6);

            tv.addView(tr);

            final View vline = new View(viewtimetable.this);
            vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
            vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            tv.addView(vline);

            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {



                        String day = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(dba.KEY_DAY));

                        String slot1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("7:30-9:10AM"));    
                        String slot2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("9:20-11:00AM"));
                        String slot3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("11:10-12:50PM"));
                        String slot4 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("1:40-3:20PM"));
                        String slot5 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("3:30-5:00PM"));

                    TableRow tr1=new TableRow(viewtimetable.this);

                                tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                           LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));     

                            TextView b=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);

                                b.setText(day);
                                b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b.setTextSize(15);
                                tr1.addView(b);


                               TextView b1=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                               TextView b2=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                               TextView b3=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                               TextView b4=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                               TextView b5=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);


                                b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b1.setTextSize(15);
                                b1.setTextColor(Color.RED);


                                b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b2.setTextSize(15);


                                b3.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b3.setTextSize(15);


                                b4.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b4.setTextSize(15);


                                b5.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b5.setTextSize(15);


                                if(day.equals("Friday"))
                                {

                                    if(slot1 != null){ 
                                    b1.setText(slot1);
                                    }
                                    if(slot2 != null)
                                    {
                                        b2.setText(slot2);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot3 != null)
                                    {
                                        b3.setText(slot3);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot4 != null)
                                    {
                                        b4.setText(slot4);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot5 != null)
                                    {
                                        b5.setText(slot5);  
                                    }

                                 }

                                else if(day.equals("Monday"))
                                {
                                    if(slot1 != null){ 
                                    b1.setText(slot1);
                                    }
                                    if(slot2 != null)
                                    {
                                        b2.setText(slot2);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot3 != null)
                                    {
                                        b3.setText(slot3);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot4 != null)
                                    {
                                        b4.setText(slot4);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot5 != null)
                                    {
                                        b5.setText(slot5);  
                                    }

                                 }



                                else if(day.equals("Tuesday"))
                                {

                                    if(slot1 != null){ 
                                    b1.setText(slot1);
                                    }
                                    if(slot2 != null)
                                    {
                                        b2.setText(slot2);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot3 != null)
                                    {
                                        b3.setText(slot3);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot4 != null)
                                    {
                                        b4.setText(slot4);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot5 != null)
                                    {
                                        b5.setText(slot5);  
                                    }

                                 }


                                else if(day.equals("Wednesday"))
                                {

                                    if(slot1 != null){ 
                                    b1.setText(slot1);
                                    }
                                    if(slot2 != null)
                                    {
                                        b2.setText(slot2);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot3 != null)
                                    {
                                        b3.setText(slot3);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot4 != null)
                                    {
                                        b4.setText(slot4);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot5 != null)
                                    {
                                        b5.setText(slot5);  
                                    }

                                 }


                                else if(day.equals("Thursday"))
                                    {

                                        if(slot1 != null){ 
                                        b1.setText(slot1);
                                        }
                                        if(slot2 != null)
                                        {
                                            b2.setText(slot2);  
                                        }
                                        if(slot3 != null)
                                        {
                                            b3.setText(slot3);  
                                        }
                                        if(slot4 != null)
                                        {
                                            b4.setText(slot4);  
                                        }
                                        if(slot5 != null)
                                        {
                                            b5.setText(slot5);  
                                        }

                                     }



                                else if(day.equals("Saturday"))
                                        {

                                            if(slot1 != null){ 
                                            b1.setText(slot1);
                                            }
                                            if(slot2 != null)
                                            {
                                                b2.setText(slot2);  
                                            }
                                            if(slot3 != null)
                                            {
                                                b3.setText(slot3);  
                                            }
                                            if(slot4 != null)
                                            {
                                                b4.setText(slot4);  
                                            }
                                            if(slot5 != null)
                                            {
                                                b5.setText(slot5);  
                                            }

                                         }

                                  tr1.addView(b1);  
                                  tr1.addView(b2);
                                  tr1.addView(b3);
                                  tr1.addView(b4);
                                  tr1.addView(b5);
                                  tv.addView(tr1);
```

Comment: For the starter, what are the values of `dba.KEY_DAY`? I think you may have typo somewhere

Comment: The problem with your loop is, your first data won't be shown because it's inside `else-block`. Remove `else` to allow all data to be shown. I can only guess from the picture, and I think your first data is Friday. Edit: I am more certain now, since I see the `day` is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Yes my first data is Friday.And day is not sorted alphabetically i guess!And the problem may be because of else but if i remove else then the part inside if would execute multiple times which is strictly undesirable.

Comment: @Andrew T. Sorry you're right.day is sorted alphabetically.I am a Stupid.

Comment: I think you don't need the `else`. Yes, the `if-block` will be called again and again, but since the flag is already 0, it won't be executed... right?

Comment: Tried removing else block and it generates exception `specified child already has parent.you must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is that the first time round (when the current row is Friday) you have flag = 1 to signal creating the columns. However the structure you have is like this:

```
while GetNextRow
    if flag = 1
        create cols, set flag = 0
    else
        process row
    endif
loop
```

On the first time through, you get Friday, create the columns and then loop.
On the second time through you get Saturday and process the row. Etc etc.

You need to take out the else. You could also put the create columns logic before the loop: that was if there is no data at all, you'd still get a screen with the columns defined and no data, rather than the blank you'd get with no data at the moment.

Cheers -

Comment: Thanks for your response.I did put the columns creating code before the loop,got rid of `if and else`.Now what exception i am getting is `specified child already has a parent.you must call removeView() on the child's parent first.Please check the Edit.
`

Comment: Can you update the code in the Question? And add the line the error is happening on? Thanks -

Comment: Please check the updated code.And i know which exception(the exception name) it's throwing but don't know on which line the error is getting generated.

Comment: I'm not an Android dev, but I think at the bottom in the updated code you're adding b1 to b5 to tr and then tr to tv on each loop of the first to last loop. This doesn't sound right. In the first loop add b2 to tr; on the second b2...on the last b5. When you exit the loop add tr to tv.

Comment: Hey problem solved.Please check my edit.Thanks again for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

As @simon and @Andrew suggested i got rid of the `if else block`.And then What i did is inside the `for loop` i created a new `Tablerow` and then added `views` to that row.

**Final Correct Code :**

```
 TableLayout tv=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
            tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            int flag=1;
            TableRow tr=new TableRow(viewtimetable.this);

            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                       LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView col1=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
            col1.setText("Day");
            col1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            col1.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(col1);


           TextView col2=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
            col2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            col2.setTextSize(15);
            col2.setText("7:30-9:10AM");
            col2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            tr.addView(col2);

           TextView col3=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
            col3.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            col3.setText("9:20-11:00AM");
            col3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            col3.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(col3);

           TextView col4=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
            col4.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            col4.setText("11:10-12:50PM");
            col4.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            col4.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(col4);

           TextView col5=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
            col5.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            col5.setText("1:40-3:20PM");
            col5.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            col5.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(col5);

           TextView col6=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
            col6.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            col6.setText("3:30-5:00PM");
            col6.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            col6.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(col6);

            tv.addView(tr);

            final View vline = new View(viewtimetable.this);
            vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
            vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            tv.addView(vline);

            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {



                        String day = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(dba.KEY_DAY));

                        String slot1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("7:30-9:10AM"));    
                        String slot2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("9:20-11:00AM"));
                        String slot3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("11:10-12:50PM"));
                        String slot4 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("1:40-3:20PM"));
                        String slot5 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("3:30-5:00PM"));

                    TableRow tr1=new TableRow(viewtimetable.this);

                                tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                           LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));     

                            TextView b=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);

                                b.setText(day);
                                b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b.setTextSize(15);
                                tr1.addView(b);


                               TextView b1=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                               TextView b2=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                               TextView b3=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                               TextView b4=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                               TextView b5=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);


                                b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b1.setTextSize(15);
                                b1.setTextColor(Color.RED);


                                b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b2.setTextSize(15);


                                b3.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b3.setTextSize(15);


                                b4.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b4.setTextSize(15);


                                b5.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b5.setTextSize(15);


                                if(day.equals("Friday"))
                                {

                                    if(slot1 != null){ 
                                    b1.setText(slot1);
                                    }
                                    if(slot2 != null)
                                    {
                                        b2.setText(slot2);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot3 != null)
                                    {
                                        b3.setText(slot3);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot4 != null)
                                    {
                                        b4.setText(slot4);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot5 != null)
                                    {
                                        b5.setText(slot5);  
                                    }

                                 }

                                else if(day.equals("Monday"))
                                {
                                    if(slot1 != null){ 
                                    b1.setText(slot1);
                                    }
                                    if(slot2 != null)
                                    {
                                        b2.setText(slot2);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot3 != null)
                                    {
                                        b3.setText(slot3);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot4 != null)
                                    {
                                        b4.setText(slot4);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot5 != null)
                                    {
                                        b5.setText(slot5);  
                                    }

                                 }



                                else if(day.equals("Tuesday"))
                                {

                                    if(slot1 != null){ 
                                    b1.setText(slot1);
                                    }
                                    if(slot2 != null)
                                    {
                                        b2.setText(slot2);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot3 != null)
                                    {
                                        b3.setText(slot3);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot4 != null)
                                    {
                                        b4.setText(slot4);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot5 != null)
                                    {
                                        b5.setText(slot5);  
                                    }

                                 }


                                else if(day.equals("Wednesday"))
                                {

                                    if(slot1 != null){ 
                                    b1.setText(slot1);
                                    }
                                    if(slot2 != null)
                                    {
                                        b2.setText(slot2);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot3 != null)
                                    {
                                        b3.setText(slot3);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot4 != null)
                                    {
                                        b4.setText(slot4);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot5 != null)
                                    {
                                        b5.setText(slot5);  
                                    }

                                 }


                                else if(day.equals("Thursday"))
                                    {

                                        if(slot1 != null){ 
                                        b1.setText(slot1);
                                        }
                                        if(slot2 != null)
                                        {
                                            b2.setText(slot2);  
                                        }
                                        if(slot3 != null)
                                        {
                                            b3.setText(slot3);  
                                        }
                                        if(slot4 != null)
                                        {
                                            b4.setText(slot4);  
                                        }
                                        if(slot5 != null)
                                        {
                                            b5.setText(slot5);  
                                        }

                                     }



                                else if(day.equals("Saturday"))
                                        {

                                            if(slot1 != null){ 
                                            b1.setText(slot1);
                                            }
                                            if(slot2 != null)
                                            {
                                                b2.setText(slot2);  
                                            }
                                            if(slot3 != null)
                                            {
                                                b3.setText(slot3);  
                                            }
                                            if(slot4 != null)
                                            {
                                                b4.setText(slot4);  
                                            }
                                            if(slot5 != null)
                                            {
                                                b5.setText(slot5);  
                                            }

                                         }

                                  tr1.addView(b1);  
                                  tr1.addView(b2);
                                  tr1.addView(b3);
                                  tr1.addView(b4);
                                  tr1.addView(b5);
                                  tv.addView(tr1);
```